# AlertDialog contextual actionbar bug on Support Library 22.2?

Tags: android, android-support-library

I think I found a bug in the Material AlertDialog of support library 22.2, but I want to check it first with the community.
The context actionbar for copy/cut text does not work fine with "android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog".

The result with with android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog (the actionbar copy/cut text is not on the top and it is not possible to click on the buttons):

[image]

If I just change the import to use "android.app.AlertDialog" the actionbar looks fine on the top:

[image]

The code:

styles.xml:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

Code from the fragment that opens the dialog:

```
public static class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new          AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_dialog, null))
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

my_dialog.xml:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <EditText
      android:hint="Text here"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

So, Is this a bug of the "android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog" right?

Comment: Nobody has the same issue?

Comment: I'm having the same issue with android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog at the moment. I think it is a bug in the support library. I'm using the default AlertDialog atm. Hopefully the next support library update will have it fixed.

Comment: @Fran I have the same issue.  There was a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=177739)  report created for this.